How do I automate testing for a mobile app using Appium?
I am working on automating tests for a mobile app (iOS/Android) using Appium. I have written some basic tests to verify if the app launches correctly, but I’m struggling with more advanced interactions, such as verifying buttons, text inputs, and handling popups.
Here’s a basic test code for launching the app:
class AppTest {
    @Test
    public void testLaunchApp() {
        AndroidDriver driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("com.example:id/button"));
        assertNotNull(element);
    }
}

I need help with creating automated tests for UI elements in Appium and best practices for testing mobile applications.
